# mathspec option clash with fontspec

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math, mathspec

I am trying to use `mathspec` `firamath-otf` package.  I am getting an option clash error with `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
%\usepackage[no-math]{mathspec}
%\usepackage[quiet]{mathspec}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.2]
\setmathsfont(Digits){Arial}
\setmathsfont(Latin){Arial}
\begin{document}
Test.
\(ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\)
\(1234567890\)
\end{document}
```

I tried loading mathspec with different options, `no-math`, `quiet` and without any options.
Nothing works. `firamath-otf` loads `unicode-math` and `unicode-math` loads `fontspec` without any options.
`mathspec` loads `fontspec` with default option `no-math`. How to sort out this clash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I missed this when you posted nine months ago.  Another solution, which might work in some situations where you cannot load the packages in a different order, or if it is loaded by a `\documentclass`, is to put this command near the top of your preamble:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
```

And now a frame challenge.

You don’t need `mathspec` if you’re loading `unicode-math`.  You aren’t using a legacy math font, or any other feature `unicode-math` doesn’t provide by itself, and as you notice, they clash.  Removing the dependency on `mathspec` also lets you compile on LuaTeX.

You can set the math letters to an OpenType font with either `\setmathfont` from `unicode-math`, or `mathastext`.  It would be preferable to write this MWE as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,  Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathfont{Arial}[range=up]
\setmathfont{Arial Italic}[range=it]
\setmathfont{Arial Bold}[range=bfup]
\setmathfont{Arial Bold Italic}[range=bfit]

\begin{document}
Test. \textit{ABC} 123 \\
\(ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\) \\
\(1234567890\) \\
\end{document}
```

or:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,  Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}
Test. \textit{ABC} 123 \\
\(ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\) \\
\(1234567890\) \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a curiosity :-) But how many font you have installed on your device? ahah. :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

I finally sorted out the issue by loading `fontspec` with option no-math before 
`firamath-otf`. The revised mwe is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.2]
\setmathsfont(Latin,Digits)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Regular,Scale=1.2]{Arial}
\begin{document}
Test.\\
\noindent ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\
\(ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\)\\
1234567890\\
\(1234567890\)
\end{document}
```

This compiles without errors and the output is as desired.
Hope that loading fontspec with no-math option  will not cause a problem because unicode-math loads it without any options. I am keeping my fingers crossed!

Comment: `firamath-otf` loads `unicode-math`, and this clashes with mathspec. Use the one or the other.

Comment: @UlrikeFishcher I am not getting any error message.  The file compiles OK.  Do you mean I can have problems later?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't combine mathspec and unicode-math.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is it possible to achieve what I want to achieve with unicode-math? Also, in the third page of documentation of mathspec, there is a comment under the heading Advanced.   This seems to say that \setmathsfont can be used by other packages if there is no first part with (<sets>). Will it not take care of the compatibility with unicode-math? Does this help in anway? Please clarify.